# Need advise on designing/architecting a Spring Batch ETL job

Tags: etl, spring-batch

I need opinions on how to go about designing the ETL process for a destination Summary table in Spring Batch.

**Situation**

I do have a (monster) query that its a combination of multiple queries joined together that produces the grid that I intent as my final summary table. The "shape" of the query is as follows:

```
select A.student_id,
       A.anoterField,
       B.anotherField,
       B.anotherField,
       C.anotherField,
       C.anotherField,
       D.anotherField
from(               
          (select s.student_id         
           from table_name
           inner join another_table
               on
           where     
           and
           group by s.student_id
           )A
inner join (select s.student_id
                   , ...
                   , ...
            from table_name
            inner join another_table
            where    
            and
            group by s.student_id
            )B
    on a.student_id = b.student_id            
inner join (select s.student_id
                   , ...
                   , ...
            from table_name
            inner join another_table
            where    
            and
            group by s.student_id
            )C  
    on a.student_id = c.student_id              
.
.
.
.
.
.
```

**Problem**

This query is ran against a Kimball Based datawarehouse for one school only and it already is a fairly intense query after all the sums,having,grouping etc that each of the inner queries do.

**Solution**

I decided I want to do an ETL job that will produce a summary table.

I decided that I am not going to do any Math at the database level. I just want to select the data it's more granular form and have the ETL do the grouping and summing for 
me.

**Design Questions**

I have managed to get familiar with Spring Batch by reading, processing, and writing items but I am still learning the framework.

So how should I design this job...

1. I was thinking in creating a as many readers as inner queries I have, then send each one of those outputs(A List of Objects) be sent to **one and only processor** this processor would have all the business logic(sums, having, grouping that the query above had) and would create one object (database row) per student. Finally, send the list of created objects to a writer, which would populate the summary table. Is that even possible since is my understanding that each step has a reader, processor, and writer?
2. Given that each step has a processor and writer, should I have each of my inner queries in a step, have its own processor which does the summary of that particular data, and write it to a file. And finally have a step that grabs all those files, the processor for that merges the data creating one Object, ending up with a List of objects and send it to the writer that populates the summary table?.

Which one would you choose?

In case of the 2nd option, Can the reader process of a step read from multiple sources? In other words can I have the final step  reads 5 or 6 files and send a Map of Lists to one processor only?

I hope it's clear let me know if not. I am just trying get my mind around designing batch jobs with Spring Batch.

Comment: if the problem lies within a slow database, can you copy all needed data and use your query with a more powerful machine/database ? just curious because i don't see the need for spring batch here

Comment: Copying the data would be quite a bit of data to be copied given the amount of schools and students that we have. The database itself it is not slow however the query that I am running that produces a certain grid with a lot of math does take sometime and not even mentioning when running it for ALL schools. So my intent was to create a spring batch job that gets me the data, and then in Java do the processing, and write it out once done. Is spring batch not the best framework for this? What is the ideal scenario for Spring Batch? Should I use Talend Open Studio for this type of work?

Comment: well as long, as you do not need transactional chunk processing spring batch might be overkill - in the end a simple mainClass with some jdbc calls could be enough, i'm not against it though ^^ just trying to keep costs low

Comment: Yes, that it's what I was leaning towards to, doing a plain old main with Spring JDBC. I got two more questions though on Spring Batch. If I want my job to run a query which resultset I use to decide the value of a parameter in a query that I have in ItemReader is SpringBatch setup for that? Or is SpringBatch framework going to "force" me to have a processor and a writer for it?

Comment: My second question is as follows. If I have an ItemReader that returns me 25 rows and in the processing I want to aggregate them together logically say by studentId. Say the first 10 rows belong
to student A, the next 5 belong to student B and the 10 remaining belong to student C.
If I set commit interval to 5 if I understand correctly 5 will be processed,aggregated, and written....but then for the next five I will have to check the already written ones, get them out aggregate them to the ones that I am currently processing and write them again.
How is that usually done?

Comment: it's better to create real questions out of this, so others can find them too